# Oracle instant client ODBC connection

Tags: r, oracle, odbc

I have a problem connecting to Oracle DB using ODBC library. ODBC drivers are installed and when I test connection through ODBC admin tool in windows it is ok. However, in R I'm running into the following problem:

```
con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "ORACLEDNS")
Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:950: 28000: [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-01005: null password given; logon denied
```

Adding PWD results in R session being unresponsive without providing any type of error.

```
con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "ORACLEDNS", PWD = "password")
```

How can I debug the issue, what might be the problem?

DB Version:

Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: Are you running a 64-bit version of R? If you are using the 32-bit version you will not be able to access the 64-bit ODBC drivers if it is these you are using. Same goes in reverse if you are using 32-bit drivers and are using R 64-bit. Just something to check before going further.

Comment: I'm using 64 bit R with 64 bit drivers.

Comment: OK, so the ODBC drivers are accessible. You provide a password but not a user ID (uid) in your connection string. Have you defined your connection to use your windows login instead of a UID?

Comment: No, I didn't. However, adding UID = username into the dbConnect call still results in the R process being unresponsive. 

con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), driver = "Oracle in OracleClient", DBQ = "DNS", UID = "username", PWD = "password")
con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), dsn = "FLITEORACLE", UID = "username", PWD = "pwd")
Both don't work for me and don't provide any further information, just R session hang.

Comment: Sounds like r is attempting to establish a connection and getting no response back from Oracle.To rule out a problem with the use of your Oracle DSN file I'd suggest you try establishing a connection in another package - Excel say. In doing so you will for sure see whether or not you are providing the correct parameters for your connection, before attempting to debug what is going on in R.

Comment: I did test connection successfully in ODBC admin panel. I'll look into checking it through Excel.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162426/discussion-between-stewart-ross-and-upsidedownride).